# jquery: Create hidden element + slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, wrapall

I have a div which contains a number of p's. Situation as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>blabla</p>
    <p>blabla</p>
    <p id="my_id">blabla</p>
    <p>blabla</p>
    <p>blabla</p>
    <p>etc...</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, a lot of blabla. I want to append `<a href>read more</a>` to `<p#my_id>`.
All the `<p>`'s after the read more link should be hidden. Once the link is clicked, it has to fade out, and all the `<p>`'s should slide in as one single object.

So i guess the following `<p>`'s would have to be wrapped in a hidden div, which later on, would slide in.

I hope my idea is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you like to have `<a href>hide more</a>` link after it?

Comment: You can't have all `<p>`'s slide in as one given your current structure. Add all those "extra" `<p>`'s together in a parent element

Comment: @HardikPatel; No need for such a link. Thanks.
@Tarun; That's why i want to wrap them, using jQuery, before sliding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, finally, thanks to you guys I've cracked it!
By adding:

```
position: relative
```

to the parent container, the jumping has completely disappeared!

```
var the_more = $( '<div id="the_more">' ).hide();
$('DIV#container').css("position", "relative");
$('DIV#container p').css("margin", "0px").css("padding", "10px 0px");
$('DIV#container p#inbetween ~ p').wrapAll( the_more );
$('<a href="#yje_more">read more</a>').appendTo('DIV#container p#inbetween').click( function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).remove()} ); $('#the_more').slideToggle(1000); } );
```

Thanks everybody for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

You could just give the elements you wish to hide a class and have them hidden by default using CSS, then just show them once the link is clicked.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYj5f/2/)

**CSS**

```
.read-more-content {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#read-more-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.read-more-content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="my_id">
    blabla <a href="#" id="read-more-link">Read More</a>
  </p>
  <p class="read-more-content">This is some hidden content</p>
  <p class="read-more-content">This is some more hidden content</p>
</div>
```

If you want to rely solely on jQuery to append the anchor and hide the 'read-more-content' you could do the following:-

[jsFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vYj5f/8/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.read-more-content').hide();
    $('<a href="#" id="read-more-link">Read More</a>').appendTo('#my_id');
    $('#read-more-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.read-more-content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="my_id">
    blabla
  </p>
  <p class="read-more-content">This is some hidden content</p>
  <p class="read-more-content">This is some more hidden content</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but i wish to insert the hidden paragraphs in a single animation, as if it were one object. You solution gives a slideToggle for every paragraph seperately.
Besides that, in this case, i don't have the possibility to add classes to the paragraphs following the link...

Thanks again.

Comment: In that case you could just wrap all of the paragraphs you wish to show in a `<div>` and then just `.slideToggle()` on that `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
function do_slidedown(element){
  $(element).slideDown("slow", function(e){
    if($(element).next().length > 0){
      do_slidedown($(element).next());
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_id ~ p').hide();
    $('#my_id').append("<a id='read_more' href='#'>read more</a>")
    $('#my_id').find("a#read_more").live("click", function(){
       $(this).hide();  // for remove link
       do_slidedown($('#my_id ~ p').first())
    });
});
```

If you want to open each `<p>` one by one then use following code...

**Solution 2:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_id ~ p').hide();
    $('#my_id').append("<a class='read_more' href='#'>read more</a>")
    $("a.read_more").live("click", function(){
       $(this).hide()
       $next_para = $(this).closest("p").next();
       if($next_para.next().length > 0) { $next_para.append("<a class='read_more' href='#'>read more</a>") }
       $next_para.slideDown();
    });
});
```

**Rebuild your solution:**
I think that jumping because of automatic margin of `<p>`, check with following.

```
var the_more = $( '<div id="the_more">' ).hide();
        $('DIV#container p').css("margin", "0px").css("padding", "10px 0px");
        $('DIV#container p#inbetween ~ p').wrapAll( the_more );
        $('<a href="#yje_more">read more</a>').appendTo('DIV#container p#inbetween').click( function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).remove()} ); $('#the_more').slideToggle(1000); } );
```

Comment: Wow, the ' ~ p'-part is new to me, but looks great!
However, still, the paragraphs animate each on their own...

Comment: Do you want to open all other `<p>`, one by one? huh?

Comment: This is representative for the type of animation i would require: http://jsfiddle.net/MYezw/1/

Thanks.

Comment: @knalpiap - just edited **Solution 1** in my answer above, hope you will enjoy it!

Comment: Not the code-direction i imagined but works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/D9hFy/ (Based on solution 1)

Doesn't this still actually technically fade every paragraph after the previous?

Comment: @knalpiap - yes, it is sliding each paragraph one by one but in sequence like sliding only one element. you can use any of the effect of jQuery like slideDown(), fandIn() etc...

Comment: I've rebuilt your solution, but the animation speed differs depending on the paragraph length: http://jsfiddle.net/fkqvS/

With the help i got here and some other resources i've found i built the following: http://jsfiddle.net/e5vXQ/

This actually works like a charm in jsFiddle but causes some weird jumping behaviour in the full layout...
Next challenge :(

Comment: My bad, the correct (updated) second link would be http://jsfiddle.net/e5vXQ/1/ Jumping still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The jump of the slideToggle is deleted from the top but still remains at the last < p>

I'll keep searching for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $afterP = $("#my_id").nextAll("p").hide();
var $readMore = $("<a></a>").attr("href", "#").addClass("read-more").text("Read more").appendTo("#my_id");

$("#container").on('click', '.read-more', function() {
    $afterP.slideToggle();
});
```

This will hide any and all `p` elements after `#my_id`, and it won't matter where abouts in the document `#my_id` occurs.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JunHA/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_id>div').hide();
    $('<a href="#" id="read-more-link">Read More</a>').appendTo('#my_id');
    $('#read-more-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('#my_id>div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="my_id">
    <p>blabla</p>
    <div>
      <p>This is some hidden content</p>
      <p>This is some more hidden content</p>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYj5f/31/)

Comment: Thanks. For the end-result animation, yes, but the div that's being slideToggled would have to be appended/wrapped using jQuery...
The visible result should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MYezw/1/

But the div should be created using jQuery.